# How do I invoke my function on keyup?

Tags: javascript, function, selector, keyup

I have a JavaScript function that I want to fire once the user enters text inside an input element. Currently I can only see the function firing if I console.log it. How do I get it to fire using keyup method?

The relevant code is below.

```
var $ = function (selector) {
    var elements = [],
      i,
      len,
      cur_col,
      element,
      par,
      fns;

      if(selector.indexOf('#') > 0) {
        selector = selector.split('#');
        selector = '#' + selector[selector.length -1];
      }

      selector = selector.split(' ');

      fns = {
        id: function (sel) {
            return document.getElementById(sel);
        },
        get : function(c_or_e, sel, par) {
            var i = 0, len, arr = [], get_what = (c_or_e === 'class') ? "getElementsByClassName" : "getElementsByTagName";
            if (par.length) {
                while(par[I]) {
                    var temp = par[i++][get_what](sel);
                    Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, Array.prototype.slice.call(temp));
                }
            } else {
                arr = par[get_what](sel);
            }
            return (arr.length === 1)? arr[0] : arr;
        }
      };

      len = selector.length;
      curr_col = document;

      for ( i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        element = selector[i];
        par = curr_col;

        if( element.indexOf('#') === 0) {
            curr_col = fns.id(element.split('#'[1]));
          } else if (element.indexOf('.') > -1) {
            element = element.split('.');

            if (element[0]) {
                par = fns.get('elements', element[0], par);
                for ( i =0; par[i]; i++) {
                    if(par[i].className.indexOf(element[1]> -1)) {

                        elements.push(par[i]);
                    }
                }
                curr_col = elements;
            } else {
                curr_col = fns.get('class', element[1], par);
            }
          } else {
            curr_col = fns.get('elements', element, par);
          }
      }
    return elements;


};
```

Comment: That function just returns elements matching a selector, it doesn't do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your method to the keyup event on the page.

You could try

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', $)
```

Or assuming you have the input element as `element` you could do

```
element.addEventListener('keyup', $)
```

Your function will be passed the `event` which you could use to investigate the state of the element if you needed that information to trigger or not trigger things in the function.

Here's a quick sample where the function that get's run on keypress is `changeColor`.

```
var COLORS = ['red', 'blue','yellow', 'black']
var NCOLORS = COLORS.length;
function changeColor(ev) {
  var div = document.getElementById('colored');
  var colorIdx = parseInt(Math.random() * NCOLORS);
  console.log(colorIdx);
  var newColor = COLORS[colorIdx];
  div.style.color = newColor
  console.log("New color ", newColor)
}
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', changeColor)
```

Though I'm not using the event (`ev`), I like to show, in the code, that I expect that variable to be available.

See it in action here - http://codepen.io/bunnymatic/pen/yyLGXg

As a sidenote, you might be careful about calling your function `$`. Several frameworks (like jQuery) use that symbol and you may run into conflicts where you're overriding the global variable `$` or where the framework overrides your version if it.

Comment: Thank you your answer is very clear. However, just noticed I'm getting an error in the console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined. It's confusing to me because I'm passing selector through the function so not sure why that's happening.

Comment: If you're tying the event with the addEventListener, you may find that the function is actually getting an `event` and not the selector you expect.  Try console.log-ing the `selector` in your loop.  You may need to use `selector.target` (assuming the selector is actually the key up event).